# Retrieve XML content of a variable

Tags: xml, powershell

I used to have an XML file that was populating a variable `([xml]$modificationData = Get-Content $modificationXmlFileName)` but now I am unable to store the file and must put it into a a different datafile, the format that I was told to do this in is:

```
xmldata = @'
  <bigSection>
    <smallSection>
      <changes>
      </changes>
    </smallSection>
  </bigSection>
'@
```

I'm not sure if the `Get-Content` cmdlet would work now if I rout it to this new variable and I'm not entirely sure what else I could use.

Also, I don't know what the `@''@` wrapping around the code means. I thought the `@` symbol was used for arrays but I dont think that it does that in this case.

Any clarification would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@'...'@` syntax is called a here string or a here document. It's a way of specifying a string without having to escape characters.

`Get-Content` is for reading files. When you call it by default, it returns an array of lines, unless you call it with the `-Raw` parameter (and then it would return one big string with all the content of the file).

So in your example, `$xmldata` is the same as if you had called `Get-Content $modificationXmlFileName -Raw`.

Since you're just trying to cast to `[xml]`, you can just do that:

```
$xmldata = [xml]@'
...
'@
```

Answer (score 1):

The `'@'  @'`  Syntax is called a **here-string** which represents a *multi-line* string with *no interpolation*.

You don't have to / can't use the `Get-Content` cmdlet using the variable, instead just cast it to xml:

```
[xml]$modificationData  = xmldata
```

Comment: Nice, I'll only add that regular strings in PowerShell can contain literal newlines and they still work